# awk/sed: how to print selection wrapped among two patterns

Tags: awk, sed

I have nmap results as shown below:

```
Starting Nmap 7.12 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-10-12 23:20 WIB
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.1
Host is up (0.0013s latency).
Not shown: 2953 closed ports, 43 filtered ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
7001/tcp open  afs3-callback
|_weblogic-t3-info: T3 protocol in use (WebLogic version: 10.3.5.0)
7002/tcp open  afs3-prserver
8001/tcp open  vcom-tunnel
|_weblogic-t3-info: T3 protocol in use (WebLogic version: 10.3.5.0)
8002/tcp open  teradataordbms
9022/tcp open  paragent
```

My question is: how to get specific pattern then print in the following format:

```
7001/tcp open  | afs3-callback | 10.3.5.0
8001/tcp open  | vcom-tunnel | 10.3.5.0
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: i have done following code, but the result still not accordance 

find ./ -type f -exec awk 'sub(/^tcp/,""){sub(/[^0-9]\/*/,""); port=$0} /weblogic\-t3\-info/{print FILENAME port }' {} \;

Comment: please edit you Q to include your best attempt to solve your problem and delete the above comment. use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box on highlighted text to format as code/data/output. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do it:

```
sed '$!N; /|/{s/\([^ ]*\)\n/| \1 /;s/_.*://;s/)//p;}; D'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand you perfectly, but you can *print selection wrapped among two pattern* very easely with `sed`:

```
sed -ne '/pattern1/,/pattern2/p' file.txt
```

(and, of course, you can have standard input redirected from a pipe as seems to be your case).